# Deskjet Printer printing faded double letters

Tags: printing, inkjet-printer

My HP deskjet printer has started printing like this, after long non usage. What can be done? - I have cleaned cartridge manually as well as using software utility provided by HP (HP 1112)

[image: Faded double letters]

Answer (score 0):

Long non use can (and does) cause ink to harden on surfaces.

Have the printer serviced and cleaned by a local repair person and then replace the cartridges with new ones.

You may find it more economical to replace the printer, or if you do not use it, use a local printing house to do your printing.

If you wish to try fixing it yourself (not normally recommended), this article was very good.

[Clean and fix HP 1112](https://www.yoyoink.com/articles/how-to-resolve-the-top-hp-deskjet-1112-printer-ink-issues/)

In part:

> Method 3. Align Your Printer Aligning your printer makes sure that
> your printer will produce accurate prints, especially if you have
> installed new ink cartridges or are switching between different paper
> thicknesses. Here are the steps to align your printer’s printhead:
>
> Make sure your printer is turned on and is connected to your computer.
> Open the HP Print Assistant window just like you did in Step 1 of
> Method 2. Go to Maintain Your Printer and then Device Services. Click
> on Align Ink Cartridges. Follow the on-screen instructions.
>
> Dirty ink cartridges will produce streaks on your printouts. Below is
> how you can clean your ink cartridges automatically:
>
> Load clean paper into your printer. Again, go to the Device Services
> tab on the HP Printer Assistant window. Click on Clean Ink Cartridges.
> After the cleaning method is done, click Print to print a test page.
> Now, examine the printed test page. For acceptable print quality,
> click Done and stop troubleshooting. For unacceptable print quality,
> click on the Second-level Clean option when you are asked to. This
> will perform another cleaning process.

Comment: any DIY techniques to fix it?

Comment: Printers have numerous parts, gears and mechanical interconnections. Local printer repair persons make a business of this because of the mechanical complexity.  You need to get a printer repair manual if you can, strip down the printer insides, and clean off all the ink. Then put in ne cartridges.

Comment: I posted a helpful cleaning article to assist you.

Comment: If you print infrequently, & especially if you tend to print text not photos, then look for a cheap laser instead of an inkjet. The 'ink' in a laser can last 10 years without issue.

Comment: Hi @John, thanks for great article. Though these techniques have not solved my problem yet. Also, buying a new cartridge is very expensive, especially for occasional use. What I do is whenever I need to print, I put the cartridge half dipped in boiling water for some time. Dont know the reason but print starts coming with some better quality for a day. Any comment?

Comment: Fixes as you describe are temporary in most cases so that is what you are seeing.